# What are the differences between the available Office365 eDiscovery tools?

Tags: exchange, powershell, microsoft-office-365

We are trying to script some eDiscovery tasks using PowerShell, and so far we have found the New-ComplianceSearch and New-MailboxSearch cmdlets. What are the differences between these two? Are there other tools available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that `New-ComplianceSearch` extends to SharePoint as well and allows for full searching across documents stored in SharePoint Online and therefore Office Online/OneDrive across the org.  Whereas `New-MailboxSearch` is only for mailbox searching.

See here: https://blogs.office.com/2015/06/17/introducing-compliance-search-in-office-365/

and specifically here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210905(v=exchg.160).aspx

> A compliance search requires at least one location. For example, mailboxes using the ExchangeLocation parameter, or SharePoint sites using the SharePointLocation parameter.

You can see additional parameters for this option:

- OneDriveLocation
- SharePointLocation